# Specify a diff tool for specific file type in Mercurial/TortoiseHg

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I am interested in tracking a binary file with Hg. For visual diffing, it would be beneficial to use a specific custom tool. Is it possible to tell TortoiseHg to use a specific tool, based on file extension?

Answer (score 1):

Just read `<TortoiseHg>/hgrc.d/MergePatterns.rc` file for common pattern and ideas, add own key(s) in `[diff-patterns]` inside global hg-config file.

Usual diff inside THG will call you tool for predefined extension